# IronPython - WPF application - Gather User input from GUI (after I close th GUI) and use it in main Python code

Tags: wpf, ironpython

I developed an IronPython-wpf application with GUI using XAML. The user enter all the inputs in the GUI and I can save them.  My problem is how I could pass those variables to my main python code after USER closes the GUI?  To close the GUI, I have a button, which closes the GUI, If the USER click it.

What I did is as follows (I just copied some portion of the code):

```
import wpf
class MyApp(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        self.opencfgfile()
        self.ictemp = self.FindName('pipent')
        self.ictemp.Text = self.ictest
        self.button = self.FindName('button')
        self.button.Click += self.onClick

    def onClick(self, sender, event):
        self.Close()

    def opencfgfile(self):
        sstest = os.environ['test']
        infile = open (sstest + '\config\test_Config.cfg' , 'r')
        for line in infile:
            if line != "\n":
               line = line[:-1]
               fields = line.split('=')
               if fields[0] == 'Initial test ID ':
                   self.ictest = fields[1].lstrip()

    def getsetname(self):
        try:
            return self.ictemp
        except AttributeError:
            return          

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = MyApp()
    Application().Run(c)
    iset = c.getsetname()
```

In my class, if I put a break point, self.ictest has a value of 'test' and self.ictemp has a value of `{System.Windows.Controls.TextBox:test}`, however if I put the break point in my main program for iset, I will get this Value: 'The name `iset` does not exist in the current context.  I really appreciate if you can help me on this issue.

Comment: What do you mean with back end? Do you want to embedd/host it in another application?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I think that I am not using the terms correctly, I meant the main python code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that the code `iset = c.getsetname()` will only be reached, after the main window is closed. The reason for this is, that `Application().Run()` contains your "application main loop", which will run until the main window is closed. So in your case, you should implement all interaction logic in `MyApp`, not in the application entry point. Everything under `if __name__ == "__main__"` should only be used for initializing some modules or similar things.

If you want to encapsulate some logic, put it in own modules and call it from `MyApp`. For example if you want to react on some button click, just do this:

```
# Short
def __init__(self, ...):
    # Init component
    self.yourButton.Click += self.OnButtonClick

def OnButtonClick(self, sender, args):
    MessageBox.Show("Clicked on some button!") # Import Message box before :)
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

This is working pretty well:

```
import wpf

from System.Windows import Window, Application

from System.Windows.Controls import TextBox

class MyApp(Window):

    box = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.Width = 200
        self.Height = 200

        self.box = TextBox()
        self.box.Height = 24
        self.box.Width = 150    

        self.Content = self.box 

    def getBoxContent(self):
        return self.box.Text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = MyApp()
    Application().Run(c)    
    print (c.getBoxContent())
```

**Info passing**

If you want to pass info to and from the ui, just create some class which hold the information. This will be the best solution:

```
import wpf

from System.Windows import Window, Application

from System.Windows.Controls import TextBox

class Information:

    InformationOne = 1
    InformationTwo = "Hello World"

class MyApp(Window):

    box = None
    information = None

    def __init__(self, info):
        self.information = info

        self.Width = 200
        self.Height = 200

        self.box = TextBox()
        self.box.Height = 24
        self.box.Width = 150    

        # Init information
        self.box.Text = self.information.InformationTwo

        self.Content = self.box 

    # Information property
    @property
    def Information(self):
        self.information.InformationTwo = self.box.Text

        return self.information

if __name__ == "__main__":

    info = Information()

    c = MyApp(info)
    Application().Run(c)    

    # Get information
    print (c.Information.InformationTwo)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do, after the main window is closed then transfer the inputs from User to the main code.  I have a Submit button "self.button.Click += self.onClick", which closes the main window " def onClick(self,s,e): self.Close()".  Is there any way to achieve this goal, except encapsulate everythin in MyApp Class?

Comment: Ok, if the window is closed, you can process in the main code. What is your excat problem there? `iset` will be available in the context after the code line `iset = c.getsetname()` is executed.

Comment: If it is a "have to" and I do not have any other option then I will.  However, when I used Tkinter to create all my GUI's I was able to create a new instance of my MyApp class and assign the object to a local variable "c" and do whatever I want to my class attributes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @HamidK i've added one more sample, is that what you are looking for? Sorry, i do not get exactly what you want...

Comment: @HamidK Add one more sample, which should fit to your needs.

Comment: First, I do not see what is teh difference in your code with mine except yoy add .Text to return of the class function.  Second,  Since I am using Visual Studio I cannot see the print output so when i assign the output to iset variable and add that to Watch list i get the same error: does not exist in the current context

Comment: @HamidK you should get the output in the `Output` window of visual studio as well

Comment: I still cannot understand why you need to have a property decorator added to pass information although with that is not working.  This is a Python class you should be able to access to class methods after you create an instance of your class.